# VB.Net Inserting information from an Access Database into an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, dataset, ms-access-2010

I'm doing my first project attempting to bind data from an .MDB file to a Windows Form project in Visual Basic. Most of the functions work off an arrays "Hubs", so I wanted to fill this array with information drawn from my database. After using the wizard to create DataSet, I created the following code.

```
Public Sub LoadData()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 15
        With Hubs(i)
            .ID = HubsDataSet.Tables("Hubs").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString 'This line is flagged as bad by the unit tests.
            .City = HubsDataSet.Tables("Hubs").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
            .Lat = HubsDataSet.Tables("Hubs").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
            .Lon = HubsDataSet.Tables("Hubs").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString
        End With
    Next

    'Load ID1ComboBox List
    For i As Integer = 0 To 15
        ID1ComboBox.Items.Add(Hubs(i).ID)
    Next

    'Load ID2ComboBox List
    For i As Integer = 0 To 15
        ID2ComboBox.Items.Add(Hubs(i).ID)
    Next

    'Set default values for Combo boxes
    ID1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
    ID2ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1

End Sub
```

While the project appears to run and function properly, I now find that all my unit tests fail, throwing an error that no Row 0 exists. In addition, if I attempt to use a for each statement instead of a for loop, the program no longer functions (it skips the lines entirely, since it does not hit a break point I inserted). I'm new to this and very confused what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is he format/structure of your "Hubs" table?  Is ID really the second data element? Remember that Item is a 0-based array as well.

Comment: In the database, the first Column is the "Index", which is the Key for the table. I can see where that'd be confusing, ID sounds like it should be a key.

Comment: And are you initializing your array of Hubs somewhere else?  I don't see you adding a new Hub to the collection in this code.

Comment: Yeah, I declared Dim Hubs(16) As Airport (a Structure of 4 strings), outside this method.

Comment: If you are getting an error stating that Row 0 does not exist, and foreach does not work through your dataset, then it may not be getting loaded correctly.  Add in a dataGridView with your dataset as the source and see if you can see rows after it loads.

Comment: Okay, I tried what you asked, and it does indeed show all the correct data at runtime. Still, I can't help but think you're on to something here. Perhaps I should do the work of learning to create a DataSet without the wizard and see if that fixes my difficulties.